# HP 2013 Ultra Slim Docking Station vs. Dell D6000 Universal Docking Station

Tags: multiple-monitors, docking-station, hp-elitebook

I'm using an older HP EliteBook 840 G4 Notebook and it currently has an HP 2013 Ultra Slim Docking Station with 2 monitors plugged in to the back via the Display Ports. I also have a Dell D6000 Universal Docking Station that isn't currently being used.

Which is better performance wise for the 2 monitors? The HP Elitebook 840 G4 has a USB 3.1 Gen 1 port, which has a max thoughput of 5Gbit/s, so if I went with the D6000, I know this would be the limit.

I can't find any specs on the docking connector on the HP 2013 Ultra Slim Docking Station.

Comment: We do not review, compare, or recommend hardware due to the opinion nature of such recommendations and because the value of the information is very time-limited due to hardware development. Please read the Help section to better understand the sorts of questions that are allowed here.

Comment: I’m not looking for a recommendation. It’s a question about the actual speed difference between USB 3.1 Gen 1 and the HP Docking Connector.

Comment: You've got all the gear, just test it - run some benchmarks on both setups and see what results you get. But unless you're doing some heavier duty computing, I doubt you'd notice a difference between the two on an avg day.